# how to insert exception stacktrace to log

Tags: java

i have code like this :

```
catch (Exception ex) {
            // Log the error
            ex.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Error in Best Quote Thread: " +  ex); 
        }
```

yes i got the error in my log like this :
2020-12-07 11:27:56 ERROR FixProtocolConvert:162 - Error in Fix Protocol Convert Thread: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
}catch (Exception ex) {
            // Log the error
            ex.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Error in FixProtocolConvert: " ,  ex); 
        }
```

i also have to try use this code but i only get like this :
2020-12-07 14:09:52 ERROR FixProtocolConvert:325 - Error in Fix Protocol Convert Thread: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException

how to get exactly position of this error ? like this example of ex.printstacktrace. so i need to log  the value of ex.printstacktrace to my logger

```
com.abcd.core.datafeed.fixProtocol(FixProtocolConvert.java:121)
        at
```

my question is how to get exactly position of this error ? because if i use that code only get log like that...
thanks all

Comment: What logger are you using?

Comment: Secondly, don´t use `printStackTrace()` and a `Logger` at the same the.

Comment: Some loggers (e.g. slf4j) recognise Exceptions as parameters and treat them specially, so try `logger.error("Error in Best Quote Thread",  ex);`. But as @Glains asked, which logger are you using?

Comment: i just created some method where i  used this - System.err.println("Some error occurred "+e.getMessage()); //eg: Some error occurred / by zero

Comment: i use Logger use Slf4j cc @Glains@tgdavies

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter passed to any log method (`info`, `warn`, ...) will be interpreted as `Exception` if it is an appropriate subclass.

```
try {
    operationThatCanFail();
catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.error("Operation failed", e); // <-- exception passed as last param 
}
```

If you need to use additional parameters:

```
try {
    operationThatCanFail();
catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.error("First {} Third {}", "Second", "Fourth", e);
}
```

Also, don´t use `e.printStackTrace()` together with a `Logger`. It is sufficient to use one form of logging. Prefer using a `Logger` instead of `System.err`, which is used by `printStackTrace()`.

Related Questions:

- [How to log exception and message with placeholders with SLF4J](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5951209)

Comment: For your example `"First {} Thrid {}", "Second", "Fourth"`, what parameters are expanded into that string, and how?

Comment: `{}` acts as a placeholder, therefore it resolves to something like _ERROR [...] - First Second Third Fourth
java.lang.NullPointerException [...]_.

Comment: printStackTrace() uses System.err, not System.out.

Comment: @VGR You are correct, i have edited the related part. Next time, feel free to suggest an edit yourself.

Comment: @Glains - Makes sense.  I misread your example the first time...thought all of "First, Second, Third, Fourth" were placeholders.